# React-Native app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED Error

Tags: react-native, android-studio

The app that was working suddenly stopped working on android. It gives Build Error. I am sharing the error below.

Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)

My android->build.gradle->buildscript file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "19.2.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I tried to upgrading kotlinVersion but it gave me error also.